# Ending iperf3 server

Tags: bash, traffic, iperf, iperf3

based off  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876341/how-can-i-stop-iperf-server-when-it-finishes) answer, how can this be done in `iperf3`. Going through the `iperf3` man page and documentation, it seems that the `-t` option no longer exists. What other ways can I implement to kill the server process after some duration or if no clients exist for some time? Is there a better / easier way than running a bash script in the back ground to kill the server after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way currently to make the iperf3 server die after some amount of time, or if no clients exist.

The link you posted mentions wanting to make an iperf2 endpoint finish after a test.  iperf3 supports a --one-off flag that causes the server to do at most one test and exit.

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks. It listens until it gets a connection, then it kills itself after the test. Another solution was a bashscript that gets the PID on instantiation of the server, and sleeps for `t` seconds before killing that PID.

Answer (score 1):

With iperf2 the -t will kill the listener after t seconds of no traffic.  It will also limit the server threads to t seconds regardless of the clients' -t times.  If - d is given, the -t only applies to server traffic threads and the iperf listener will remain.

Another option to kill the listener after a test is to set -P 1 on the server command line

Bob

https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is if you dont get a connection after a certain period or the client side connection times out. You can try doing a server to server connection. This coupled with the 1 off option will close to server.

example using python2:

```
import subprocess
import time
import numpy as np

iperf_location = r'C:\Users\iperf3.exe'

server_IP = '192.168.0.10'
client_IP = '192.168.0.11'

server_command = iperf_location + ' -s -B ' + server_IP + ' --one-off'
client_command = iperf_location + ' -c ' + server_IP + ' -B ' + client_IP

#this command does a server to server connection. This way the server will close out correctly
#in the event that the client cannot connect
fail_command = iperf_location + ' -c ' + server_IP + ' -B ' + server_IP

subprocess.Popen(server_command)
time.sleep(1)
x = subprocess.Popen(client_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

speed_list = []
for item in x.stdout:
    item = str(item)
    #print item
    if 'Mbits/sec' in item.split(' '):
        if "sender\n" not in item.split(' '):
            if "receiver\n" not in item.split(' '):
                x = item.split(' ').index('Mbits/sec')
                speed_list.append(float(item.split(' ')[x-1]))

if len(speed_list) != 0:
    avg_data_rate = np.average(speed_list)
    print avg_data_rate
else:
    avg_data_rate = 0
    print 'Test failed. Doing server direct test to ensure iperf cleans up correctly'
    subprocess.check_output(fail_command)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you started `iperf3` in daemon mode with the `-D` option

```
iperf3 -s -D
```

Then you can stop it by sending it a `SIGHUP` signal (signal number 1)

```
pkill -HUP iperf3
```

or

```
pkill -1 iperf3
```